# Open specific image in fancybox from main image area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, fancybox-2

I have fancybox opening when I click on the "main image" area in my gallery, and no matter what image is open fancybox always starts at the first image in the gallery. For example when a user clicks on the 4th image thumbnail, it loads into the "main image" area correctly, but when clicking on the main image fancybox starts from the beginning.

I understand why it's doing this, because the main image area is wrapped in:

```
<a rel="gallery" class="fancybox" href="#hover0"> <img/> </a>
```

But what I would like to happen is to have the href '#hover0' change to #hover2, #hover3, #hover4 etc when the corresponding image is loaded in the main area. Not sure how to go about doing this.

Test Page: http://www.pixlsnap.com/j/testb.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so I have tested this by saving your whole page (along with all the resources linked to your live site, so glad the images had a direct path), you could do the following, but before I go to that there is a script error that you need to correct:

```
 $(function(){
        // Bind a click event to a Cloud Zoom instance.
        $('#1').bind('click',function(){
```

^ You have not closed this function correctly, it needs an extra `});` at the end.

Now there are 2 things you need to do for your problem:

1) Paste the following code **above** the function I mentioned previously (the order matters so **it needs** to be above it):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#imgconstrain img').on('click',function(){
        $new_hoverid = $('img.cloudzoom-gallery-active').attr('id');
        $('#1').closest('a').attr('href','#'+$new_hoverid);
    });
});
```

To explain what this code is doing, when the big image is *clicked*, we are going to get the active image, in case you haven't noticed, when you click on a thumbnail it gets the class `cloudzoom-gallery-active`. So, on click of the bigger image, we are going to retrieve the `id` of the thumbnail with the `cloudzoom-gallery-active` class.

Now, since we are getting the `id` attribute, each image should have a unique id. So here we go for the second part:

2) Give your thumbnails image a unique id like:

```
<li><img class = 'cloudzoom-gallery' id="hover1" src ="http://brecksargent.com/slideshowpro/p.php?a=eXt1NExlZT1uemwuIjItOjI6Hys4OzouNio%2BNC4iKyAiPjQjJjs%2FNCY%2BLiY0&amp;m=1383849642" alt ="LIG Hippie Commune" data-cloudzoom = "useZoom: '.cloudzoom', image:'http://brecksargent.com/slideshowpro/albums/album-16/lg/lig5_on.jpg', zoomImage:'http://brecksargent.com/slideshowpro/albums/album-16/lg/lig5_on.jpg' "> </li>
                                <!-- ^ here -->

<li><img class = 'cloudzoom-gallery' id="hover2" src ="http://brecksargent.com/slideshowpro/p.php?a=cX12XnxkJXl0bSczJSgwOzIDOjY5OyYzKzE8LTI%2BMiU%2BJzE%2FOicjKD8nNyM%3D&amp;m=1383853420" alt ="Dunno weird though" data-cloudzoom = "useZoom: '.cloudzoom', image:'http://brecksargent.com/slideshowpro/albums/album-16/lg/dod_on.jpg', zoomImage:'http://brecksargent.com/slideshowpro/albums/album-16/lg/dod_on.jpg' "> </li>
                                <!-- ^ here -->
```

...till `hover6` and that's it.

Let me know if that works for you and feel free to ask if the explanation wasn't clear enough ^-^

### Edits:

So as per the comments, here's a few things to be done:

1) In your this anchor tag:

```
<div id="imgconstrain">
<a rel="gallery" class="fancybox" href="#hover0">
<img class = "cloudzoom" id="1" src =
```

- Take out `rel="gallery"` (this is the reason fancybox is showing from start on click of next) and remove `fancybox` class and instead add `open-fancybox` (the reason for this is coming later)

2) All these lines:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function displayCaption() {
            var caption = document.getElementById('caption');
            caption.innerHTML = this.alt;
        }

        document.getElementById('1').onclick = displayCaption;
        document.getElementById('2').onclick = displayCaption;
        //....
</script>
```

- is not needed, we will do this in a smaller way

3) Like I mentioned previously, please add the `id`s here:

```
<li><img class = 'cloudzoom-gallery' id="hover1" src ="http://brecksargent.com/slideshowpro/p.php?a=eXt1NExlZT1uemwuIjItOjI6Hys4OzouNio%2BNC4iKyAiPjQjJjs%2FNCY%2BLiY0&amp;m=1383849642" alt ="LIG Hippie Commune" data-cloudzoom = "useZoom: '.cloudzoom', image:'http://brecksargent.com/slideshowpro/albums/album-16/lg/lig5_on.jpg', zoomImage:'http://brecksargent.com/slideshowpro/albums/album-16/lg/lig5_on.jpg' "> </li>
                                    <!-- ^ here -->
<li><img class = 'cloudzoom-gallery' id="hover2" src ="http://brecksargent.com/slideshowpro/p.php?a=cX12XnxkJXl0bSczJSgwOzIDOjY5OyYzKzE8LTI%2BMiU%2BJzE%2FOicjKD8nNyM%3D&amp;m=1383853420" alt ="Dunno weird though" data-cloudzoom = "useZoom: '.cloudzoom', image:'http://brecksargent.com/slideshowpro/albums/album-16/lg/dod_on.jpg', zoomImage:'http://brecksargent.com/slideshowpro/albums/album-16/lg/dod_on.jpg' "> </li>
                                    <!-- ^ here -->
```

- and so on till the last image.

4) Now the final piece:

```
$('ul#carousel.elastislide-list img').on('click',function(){
            //here we get the updated id (hover1, hover2 etc.)
            //and pass it to the cloud-zoomed anchor tag
    $new_hoverid = $('img.cloudzoom-gallery-active').attr('id');
    $('#imgconstrain a').attr('href','#'+$new_hoverid);

    //get the caption of the thumbnail image and set it to the
    //p tag with id caption
    caption_text = $(this).attr('alt');
    var caption_element = document.getElementById('caption');
    caption_element.innerHTML = caption_text;
});

    //what this code does is, when the cloud-zoomed image is clicked,
    //we get the updated href (which is what the above code does)
    //and we are going to make that href get clicked so that the fancybox opens
$('#imgconstrain a.open-fancybox').on('click',function(){
    $to_open = $(this).attr('href');
    $('a.fancybox[href="'+$to_open+'"]').click();
});
```

});

You can take out this code which was in my previous answer as I have already placed it in the new one:

<strike>$(document).ready(function(){</strike>

$('#imgconstrain img').on('click',function(){

$new_hoverid = $('img.cloudzoom-gallery-active').attr('id');

$('#1').closest('a').attr('href','#'+$new_hoverid);

});

**[Full code pastebin](http://pastebin.com/VN5c0CJg)**

Let me know if it works for you :)

Comment: @I Can Has Cheezburger That worked great, thank you! It however seems to have broken the captions that load on the thumbnail click. I think this is because the script I'm using is loading the old ids (1,2,3) but when changing it to hover1, hover2, hover3 it still doesn't seem to work, any idea why? Thanks again!

Comment: @screth I see. I didn't notice any captions while working on that link. Can I possibly see a test page of this?

Comment: @screth Also, I just noticed this is not really a clean solution since once you click on a image, and slide, it starts from beginning again when it should actually show the next, I'll try fixing that up too.

Comment: @I Can Has Cheezburger Here is the original test with the captions in the lower left http://www.pixlsnap.com/j/testb_copy.php Yes the first slide shows itself twice, I have seen this before and think there is a way to fix it, just gotta find the solution again! Thank you.

Comment: @I Can Has Cheezburger Works great, thank you! If you want a cheezburger on me let me know :)